# What would be the impact if I write all the test coverage in single test class with different methods?

Tags: apex, unit-test, code-coverage

We are facing challenge with parallel execution and end up with the error "salesforce-com-unable-to-lock-row-unable-to-obtain-exclusive-access", So we thought of writing all such classes in single class with different methods.

Is it same as un checking parallel execution?(it is solved our problem but not approved by business)

Will the test methods in single class will execute in parallel or sequential? I have tested with this scenario and test class is passed.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Uday, parallel execution means tests run in parallel, and every method is itself a separate unit test, so I think SF might run some methods even of the same class in parallel as well(if you have not unchecked the checkbox).

Comment: 1) Executing the test classes in sequential mode (Execution time is the factor, even for small move to prod would require to wait for long execution time)
2) Test.IsRunningtest() - we have used this option for time being to avoid the failures.
3) Executing all the test classes in one Test class using different test methods, this is tested and executed successfully.

TestClass1 {

testmethod(){
TestClass2();
}

testmethod(){
TestClass3();
}

}.. Which one is the best solution?